# Can't Alter Login

Tags: sql-server

I created a SQL Server login for an application user and forgot to uncheck the policy options.  Now when I try to uncheck the options from SQL server management studio I get: 
The CHECK_POLICY and CHECK_EXPIRATION options cannot be turned OFF when MUST_CHANGE is ON. 
How can I make the policy changes short of removing the user and starting over?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Check out this link:
[Fix a SQL Server Login which has MUST_CHANGE set to ON](http://www.webofwood.com/2009/01/29/fix-a-sql-server-login-which-has-must_change-set-to-on/)

You can use the following query to fix that:

```
USE Master
GO
ALTER LOGIN UserName WITH PASSWORD = 'password'
GO
ALTER LOGIN UserName WITH
      CHECK_POLICY = OFF,
      CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF;
```

Replacing UserName and password with the proper values.

The link will also walk you through the process of fixing it in the management studio interface.

Comment: Thank you! You have prevented me from going bald, as I was tearing my hair out by the handful.  "Simple" query language indeed!

Answer (score 21):

Basically, just change the password only, then hit OK.  Open it back up and you can uncheck the Enforce password boxes.

Comment: That does work, but script in the other answer is definitely more useful :)

Comment: This solution was much quicker and easier.